# PDOException in Connector.php line 47: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1

I am working with Laravel 5. Its working fine on localhost. when i transfer live server from localhost it shows error when i am trying to login.
`PDOException in Connector.php line 47:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Permission denied`

I tried by changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` but it also not working.

Comment: Are username and password correct?

Comment: Yes, username and password are correct.

Comment: @MuhammadYasir can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

If you are on CentOS, try to disable SELinux.

If you don't want to disable, go to Terminal, grant SU and

> setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1

Thanks to [@Aung Myat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7124607/aung-myat) for the last line.